# Other shortcuts similar to $\pm$?

Tags: notation

In writing proofs, I'll sometimes end up with two separate but similar results, such as $[a] + [b] = [a + b]$ and $[a] \times [b] = [a \times b]$.

Out of curiosity, is there some *standard* notation to denote two operations at once, besides the $\pm$ sign? For example, maybe there's some symbol like $\ast$ that represents addition and multiplication?

Comment: Maybe say "the map $x\mapsto [x]$ is a ring homomorphism"?  My idea is not to find a compact notation, but a sentence that communicates effectively.

Comment: I would think that $\pm$ communicates more effectively than writing two equations, one with $+$ and one with $-$; it also shows the meaning of the results more elegantly. I'm just trying to find other notations like this, that are both compact and effective.

Comment: Yes, but I think the $\pm$ sign is effective communication.  If there were an equivalent $*$ to mean $\times$ or $+$, I don't think it would be effective communication.

Comment: The symbol $\pm$ has no business here,it's not a binary operation, nor is it short for two binary operations. The string of symbols $a\pm b =c$ is short hand notation for the statement $a+b=c\lor a-b=c$, $\pm$ is not a binary operation at all.

Comment: There isn't a widely-known symbol to denote both $+$ and $\times$ (if there is one at all) so if you were to use a symbol it would just make things *less* clear because not many people would recognize it.

Comment: You can abbreviate by saying something like: let $*\in \{+,\times\}$, for all $a,b$ the following holds: $[a]*[b]=[a*b]$. Clearly $*$ can take multiple meaning, the same way $+$ in $[a] + [b] = [a + b]$ has multiple meanings. That's a problem that arises from the way you set up question.

Comment: @GitGud Isn't it in some cases? For example, the quadratic equation

Comment: @Sim If you're talking about $$ax^2+bx+c=0\iff x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},$$ then no. As you know - and as I have pointed out - the RHS of the equivalence is short for $$x=\dfrac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\lor x=\dfrac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$